# Sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to first prove whether the following series is convergent, and then find its limit if it exists:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}$

So, I have proved that it is convergent, but I'm having trouble in finding the limit. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Consider telescopes.  $\sum_{n=1}^M \frac 1n -\frac 1{n+2} = \sum_{n=1}^M \frac 1n - \sum_{n=1}^M\frac 1{n+2} = \sum_{n=1}^m\frac 1n -\sum_{n=3}^{M+2} \frac 1n = 1 + \frac 12 - \frac 1{M+1} - \frac 1{M+2}$ so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 - \frac 1{n+2} = \lim_{M\to \infty}(1+\frac 12 -\frac 1{M+1} -\frac 1{M+2})$.  And what that equal should be intuitively obvious.  ANd proving it should be, like an $N, \epsilon$ proofs irritatingly tedious but ultimately straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is due to 
$$
\frac{1}
{n} - \frac{1}
{{n + 2}}
$$ 
write it as 
$$
a_n  = \left( {\frac{1}
{n} - \frac{1}
{{n + 1}}} \right) + \left( {\frac{1}
{{n + 1}} - \frac{1}
{{n + 2}}} \right)
$$
At this point both the terms in the brackets telescoping. So I thin now it is easy.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac 1n -\frac 1{n+2}) = $ (if it exists at all)

$\lim_{M\to \infty}(\sum_{n=1}^M \frac 1n -\frac 1{n+2})$ and

$\sum_{n=1}^M (\frac 1n -\frac 1{n+2}) = \sum_{n=1}^M \frac 1n - \sum_{n=1}^M\frac 1{n+2} = $

$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac 1n -\sum_{n=3}^{M+2} \frac 1n =$

$ 1 + \frac 12 - \frac 1{M+1} - \frac 1{M+2}$

So $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac 1n -\frac 1{n+2}) = \lim_{M\to \infty}(1 + \frac 12 - \frac 1{M+1} - \frac 1{M+2})$ which....

I'll leave to you.

Answer (score -1):

The ans is $\frac{3}{2}$. Compute the sequence of partial sum and you'll figure it out.

Spoiler :

$S_n = (1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n})-(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{n+2})$

$= (1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n})+(1+\frac{1}{2})-(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{n+2})$

$=(\gamma_{n} + ln {n}) + \frac{3}{2} - (\gamma_{n+2} + ln (n+2))$

$=(\gamma_n - \gamma_{n+2}) +ln {\frac{n}{n+2}}+ \frac{3}{2}$

Therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n = \frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Op first asked a different series that's why my initial ans was different. I've edited it now. So whoever it is who have given the downvote, I'd love to hear the explanation.